# Many-to-Many relationship with extra column in spring mvc restful webservice getting StackOverflow error and more

Tags: mysql, json, hibernate, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm new to the things I'm using, so if anyone can help. It is very much appreciated.

I'm using Spring MVC, Hibernate, Maven, MySql and Jackson Json. I have a many-to-many relationship that has an extra column for a date value. I have 2 main entities `Party` and `User`. I also have an associative table name `PartyMember` that has an `embeddable` as an id.

I get a

> java.lang.StackOverflowError

error whenever I retrieve a record that already has a `partyMember`. I also get a

> org.hibernate.TransientObjectException

when I try to add a `partyMember` in the association table.

I have tried `@JsonManagedReference`, `@JsonBackReference`, `@JsonIdentityInfo` and none of them have worked so far. I also have been to numerous posts and sites talking about my problem but none of the suggested solutions have worked for me.

So, I humbly ask for anyone's help.

I attached my code below. Thanks

**Party.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Party")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Party implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "name", length = 45, unique = true)
private String name;

@Column(name = "startDateTime")
private String startDateTime;

@Column(name = "endDateTime")
private String endDateTime;

@Column(name = "destination")
private String destination;

@Column(name = "destLong", columnDefinition = "DECIMAL(20, 10)")
private Float destLong;

@Column(name = "destLat", columnDefinition = "DECIMAL(20, 10)")
private Float destLat;

@Column(name = "status")
private String status;

@Column(name = "createdDate", updatable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date createdDate;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "createdBy", referencedColumnName = "id")
private User createdBy;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "pk.party", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
@Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
@JsonManagedReference(value = "party")
private Set<PartyMember> partyMembers = new HashSet<PartyMember>(0);

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getStartDateTime() {
    return startDateTime;
}

public void setStartDateTime(String startDateTime) {
    this.startDateTime = startDateTime;
}

public String getEndDateTime() {
    return endDateTime;
}

public void setEndDateTime(String endDateTime) {
    this.endDateTime = endDateTime;
}

public String getDestination() {
    return destination;
}

public void setDestination(String destination) {
    this.destination = destination;
}

public Float getDestLong() {
    return destLong;
}

public void setDestLong(Float destLong) {
    this.destLong = destLong;
}

public Float getDestLat() {
    return destLat;
}

public void setDestLat(Float destLat) {
    this.destLat = destLat;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}

public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}

public User getCreatedBy() {
    return createdBy;
}

public void setCreatedBy(User createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
}

public Set<PartyMember> getPartyMembers() {
    return partyMembers;
}

public void setPartyMembers(Set<PartyMember> partyMembers) {
    this.partyMembers = partyMembers;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "[id : " + getId() + "] [name : " + getName() + "] [startDateTime : " + getStartDateTime()
            + "] [endDateTime : " + getEndDateTime() + "] [destination : " + getDestination() + "] [destLong : "
            + getDestLong() + "] [destLat : " + getDestLat() + "] [status : " + getStatus() + "] [createdDate : "
            + getCreatedDate() + "] [createdBy : " + getCreatedBy() + "]";
}

}
```

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "fName", length = 25)
private String fName;

@Column(name = "lName", length = 30)
private String lName;

@Column(name = "email", length = 45, unique = true)
private String email;

@Column(name = "password", length = 20)
private String password;

@Column(name = "createdDate", updatable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date createdDate;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "pk.user", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
@Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
@JsonManagedReference(value = "user")
private Set<PartyMember> partyMembers = new HashSet<PartyMember>(0);

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getfName() {
    return fName;
}

public void setfName(String fName) {
    this.fName = fName;
}

public String getlName() {
    return lName;
}

public void setlName(String lName) {
    this.lName = lName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}

public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}

public Set<PartyMember> getPartyMembers() {
    return partyMembers;
}

public void setPartyMembers(Set<PartyMember> partyMembers) {
    this.partyMembers = partyMembers;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "[id : " + getId() + "] [fname : " + getfName() + "] [lname : " + getlName() + "] [email : " + getEmail()
            + "] [password : " + getPassword() + "] [createdDate : " + getCreatedDate() + "]";
}

}
```

**PartyMemberId.java**

```
@Embeddable
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class PartyMemberId implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@ManyToOne
private Party party;

@ManyToOne
private User user;

public Party getParty() {
    return party;
}

public void setParty(Party party) {
    this.party = party;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
}
```

**PartyMember.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PartyMember")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "id")
@AssociationOverrides({ @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.party", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "partyId") ),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.user", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userId") ) })
public class PartyMember implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private PartyMemberId pk = new PartyMemberId();

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "joinDate", updatable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
private Date joinDate;

public PartyMemberId getPk() {
    return pk;
}

public void setPk(PartyMemberId pk) {
    this.pk = pk;
}

@Transient
@JsonBackReference(value = "user")
public User getUser() {
    return getPk().getUser();
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    getPk().setUser(user);
}

@Transient
@JsonBackReference(value = "party")
public Party getParty() {
    return getPk().getParty();
}

public void setParty(Party party) {
    getPk().setParty(party);
}

public Date getJoinDate() {
    return joinDate;
}

public void setJoinDate(Date joinDate) {
    this.joinDate = joinDate;
}
}
```

**PartyServiceImpl.java**

```
@Transactional
@Service(value = "partyService")
public class PartyServiceImpl implements PartyService {

@Autowired
public PartyDao partyDao;

@Override
public Party getParty(Integer id) {
    return partyDao.getParty(id);
}

@Override
public List<Party> getAll(int pNo, int pSize) {
    return partyDao.getAll(pNo, pSize);
}

@Override
public Party createParty(Party p, Integer id) {
    User u = new User();
    u.setId(id);
    p.setCreatedBy(u);
    PartyMember partyMember = new PartyMember();
    partyMember.setUser(u);
    partyMember.setParty(p);
    partyMember.setJoinDate(new Date());

    p.getPartyMembers().add(partyMember);

    return partyDao.createParty(p);
}

@Override
public int deleteParty(Integer id) {
    return partyDao.deleteParty(id);
}

@Override
public boolean checkName(String name) {
    if (partyDao.getPartyByName(name) != null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public Party updateParty(Party p) {
    return partyDao.updateParty(p);
}

@Override
public Party addMember(Party p, Integer id) {
    User u = new User();

    u.setId(id);

    PartyMember partyMember = new PartyMember();
    partyMember.setUser(u);
    partyMember.setParty(p);

    p.getPartyMembers().add(partyMember);
    return partyDao.updateParty(p);
}

}
```

Comment: Where did you get this code?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do the work of the `JoinTables` yourself with the `PartyMember` and `PartyMemberId`. Simplify your `Entities` to just `User` and `Party` like so:

```
@Entity
public class Party implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    private User createdBy;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<User> partyMembers = new HashSet<User>();
```

and

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Party> parties = new HashSet<Party>();
```

I think this will do everything you want, correct me if I'm wrong.

Also, since you're using Spring, just have the `Rest` points return an `Entity`, or `Page<Entity>` directly (such as `User` or `Party`) and it will manage all the `Json` for you. Finally, you should go to [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) and get a starter application that uses all the latest jars. This will be much better than `SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`.